# From additivity of the measure, couldn't we prove the $\sigma -$additivity?

Tags: measure-theory

The definition for $\mathbb P$ to be a (probability) measure on a set $(\Omega ,\mathcal F)$ one axiom is the $\sigma -$additivity, i.e. $$\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb P(A_i),$$
for $A_i$ disjoints.

But if we give as axiom the additivity of the measure instead of the $\sigma -$additivity, i.e. $$\mathbb P\left(A_1\cup A_2\right)=\mathbb P(A_1)+\mathbb P(A_2)$$ for $A_1,A_2$ disjoint, can't we deduce the $\sigma -$additivity ? I guess it is not true, but I can't find a counter example.

I know that for example, on $([0,1], 2^{[0,1]},m)$ and $m$ be the Lebesgue measure, then there are disjoints sets $A,B$ in $2^{[0,1]}$ s.t. $$m(A\cup B)<m(B)-m(A),$$
so since additivity doesn't hold, $m$ can't be a measure, but I can't find an application $\nu:2^{[0,1]}\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $\nu$ is additive but not $\sigma -$additive. Any example ?

Comment: "Find an example?" ... maybe not.  Constructing an example of a finitely-additive but not countably-additive measure on a sigma-algebra requires the axiom of choice.  Showing such an example exists? yes, with ZFC.  For an example, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter .

Comment: @GEdgar: Thank you :) **1)** In fact, why do we want $\sigma -$additivity, and not only additivity ? What is the motivation behind ? **2)** Moreover, if you construct an example of a finitely additive measure that is not $\sigma -$additive, doesn't it mean that such a measure exist ? Because to me *"Constructing an example of a finitely-additive but not countably-additive measure on a sigma-algebra requires the axiom of choice."* **and** *"Showing such an example exists?"* mean the same... it's not ?

Comment: Finite additivity is fine for some things.  But not for others.  The "limit theorems" in the Lebesgue theory of integration depend on sigma-additivity. These limit theorems are used frequently in modern analysis. You may say the countable additivity is the principal difference between the Riemann and Lebesgue integrals.

Comment: @GEdgar: Oh, I see, thank you. And for **2)** ?